# Entity Framework with IoT Background Application

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, entity-framework-core, windows-10-iot-core

Visual Studio provides a ["**Background Application (IoT)**" template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MicrosoftIoT.WindowsIoTCoreProjectTemplates)  which i want to use to create a **headless** webservice. To persist some data i want to use [**Entity Framework** with SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started) as DB-Engine .

After upgrading UWP to 5.2.2 and installing Sqlite and EFCore.Tools and adding a DbContext i wanted to migrate the first version. It fails:

> PM> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration
>
> Project 'BackgroundApplication4' is a Windows Runtime component. The Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools don't support this type of project.

I thinks it's not a problem with EF itself, because it worked for me with a simple "Blank App". Now there are some questions coming up: Is a "Background Application" really a WinRT-Component and has a different (unsupported) handling by EF?

I thought UWP is an [extension of WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981237/is-windows-universal-platform-the-replacement-of-winrt-of-windows-8-and-windows) so basically each UWP-App must be a WinRT-Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF in a Windows Runtime component is a no-go; but that is not so bad since WinRT component can depend on class libraries. So move all your EF classes to a own class libary and consume that library from your background task in your Windows Runtime component.

By doing this you can also use the same class library also in the foreground app when needed.

P.s. Check the github page of EFCore and UWP. There are lot of issues especially in combination with .net native. so using EF.core in UWP will cause you lot of headache; but it is possible.

Comment: I tried your suggestion: next to my background app i created a (universal) class library.

PM> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration
Startup project 'LedManager' is a Windows Runtime component. The Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools don't support this type of project.

Comment: Make a normal app project to just generate the migration in the class library?

Comment: Just in this moment i tried this out:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6098
(what you just said) and it worked for me. The solution contains now three projects: one dummy UWP-App, one class-lib for the persistence and one background-app project.