# SQLite3 database file location for WinRT

Tags: sqlite, uwp, directory, c++-winrt

I have been struggling for a while now on where I should put some SQLite3 database files that  will need read and write access. You can see from my question that I am writing my app in WinRT, and that is where the problem starts. I have several choices on where to put the files, but they are all User level access. My app will have multiple users and I can not think of a way to share the same file amongst all the users. I have tried many ideas. None of them have panned out. Microsoft has WinRT so locked down as far as my ability to put files where I want them. I was thinking the ProgramData folder might make sense. But no.

Any one have a known, can't miss way for me to use any folder I want to, within reason? Next, I am going to try the Public User Documents folder and see if I have any luck using it. Not ideal, but I have seen other apps use it and I always wonder why. I am beginning to think I finally figured it out. Thanks for any thoughts you may have from a very frustrated coder.

Comment: WinRT doesn't impose any restrictions. The UWP, on the other hand, does. Are you targeting the UWP, and if so, is there a particular reason to do so?

Comment: I am confused about what the difference is between them. I have been using them interchangeably. I will do some more research into how I got here.

Comment: Here is where my confusion exists. 1) When I create a new Blank Page for C++/WinRT in VS2019 the description is "A single page ...for a C++/WinRT Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app.", so which is it? 2) I am using namespace winrt. 3) I just need to place my database files for SQLite3 in a folder of my choosing. So far, SQLite refuses to read or write them from any folder but appdata/packages.

Comment: It seems to me that WinRT and UWP must be related. In simplest terms, UWP is derived from WinRT. It is also my understanding that UWP has been dropped by MS. Since you claim WinRT will allow me to access other folders, can you write a few lines of code that opens a database with sqlite3_open(), fetches the data, and displays it. One last thing, I want to target WinRT, not UWP. I think I am doing that in my code. How do I verify that?

Comment: Your app is a UWP app based on your information. You might try WinUI3(Windows App SDK) app, it uses WinRT API and doesn't have the restrictions like UWP has. Win32 and .NET API are also supported in WinUI3 apps. You can use C# or C++/WinRT to create WinUI3 app. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/create-your-first-winui3-app#packaged-create-a-new-project-for-a-packaged-c-or-c-winui-3-desktop-app

Comment: Thanks. That thought had crossed my mind. Now if it is not to hard to convert the code I have already written to WinUI3, then maybe i can get past this.

Comment: The *"UWP"* is a containerized execution environment. It was introduced with two primary goals: Consolidating an API surface across device families and strict regulation of access to system resources. Its most visible asset—a new UI framework—never received a name. Initially accessible to UWP applications only, it wasn't technically a part of the UWP. WinUI 2 established this by moving the UI out of the OS and making it accessible to classic desktop applications. WinUI 3 went a step further in dropping UWP support altogether.

Comment: The *"Windows Runtime"* follows the tradition of poor naming decisions. Like COM, it describes a language-agnostic binary contract for reusable components alongside platform services for type discovery and activation. It is **not** concerned with "runtime" services. As a technology, it stands on its own feet. It is unrelated to the UWP other than coincidence: The UWP was the first mainstream client using this technology. The WinRT and UWP are orthogonal, but the lack of concise terminology (and naming) used in communication continues to confuse developers to this day.

Comment: Frustration aside, what I read into the question is approximately this: *"I want to use the 'UWP UI' framework, but not the UWP resource restrictions. Is that possible?*" If the above made any sense, this would be the response: *"Yes. Use WinUI 3 (part of the Windows App SDK)."* If you follow this advice, and C++ is the programming language of choice, you'll find yourself well set up to enter a world of pain.

Comment: For the curious, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38462099/1889329) has a far more complete and accurate description of events that lead up to the UWP. In short, it is the evolution to *yet another* unnamed technology.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. I have most of the code ported to WinUI 3 , BUT the world of hurt seems to have struck already. Several functions that are not in WinUI 3, need to be rewritten, and I am struggling. Going to make a new post for one of those problems right now.